# Exported Shared Modules after import not recognizing in angular 10

Tags: angular, module, lazy-loading

Currently I have two shared Modules in my project

1. shared.module
2. shared.material.module.

Both the modules are imported by root level modules and are available everywhere.

Now I am trying to divide shared.module into two parts:

pub.shared.modules
and admin.shared.module
where some of the common modules will still be used in
shared.module.ts

So, I am importing shared.module in both admin.module and pub.shared.module

Expecting that I don't have to import modules/components/pipes from shared.module to these ones.

But despite getting imported, I have to import it again in the admin.shared.module and pub.shared.module to work.

The error I am getting is in my component pub.layout.component is not recognizing.

My idea is to import pub.shared.module as a lazy-loaded module for public pages including the home page. But I am not importing this module in my root level module.

shared.module.ts

```
import { SharedMaterialModule } from './shared-material.module';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { PerfectScrollbarModule } from 'ngx-perfect-scrollbar';
import { SidebarTopComponent } from './components/sidebar-top/sidebar-top.component';

// ALL TIME REQUIRED
import { NotificationsComponent } from './components/notifications/notifications.component';
import { SidenavComponent } from './components/sidenav/sidenav.component';
import { BreadcrumbComponent } from './components/breadcrumb/breadcrumb.component';
import { AppComfirmComponent } from './services/app-confirm/app-confirm.component';
import { AppLoaderComponent } from './services/app-loader/app-loader.component';

// DIRECTIVES
import { FontSizeDirective } from './directives/font-size.directive';
import { ScrollToDirective } from './directives/scroll-to.directive';
import { AppDropdownDirective } from './directives/dropdown.directive';
import { DropdownAnchorDirective } from './directives/dropdown-anchor.directive';
import { DropdownLinkDirective } from './directives/dropdown-link.directive';
import { snSideNavToggleDirective } from './directives/ecom-side-nav-toggle.directive';
// PIPES
import { RelativeTimePipe } from './pipes/relative-time.pipe';
import { ExcerptPipe } from './pipes/excerpt.pipe';
import { GetValueByKeyPipe } from './pipes/get-value-by-key.pipe';

// SERVICES
import { RoutePartsService } from './services/route-parts.service';
import { AuthGuard } from './services/auth/auth.guard';
import { AppConfirmService } from './services/app-confirm/app-confirm.service';
import { AppLoaderService } from './services/app-loader/app-loader.service';
import { DialogSearchComponent } from './components/pub-header/dialog-search/dialog-search.component';
// import { APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonApiService } from './services/commonapi.services';
import { ScriptService } from './services/script.service';

const classesToInclude = [
  DialogSearchComponent,
  SidebarTopComponent,
  SidenavComponent,
  NotificationsComponent,
  BreadcrumbComponent,
  AppComfirmComponent,
  AppLoaderComponent,
  FontSizeDirective,
  ScrollToDirective,
  AppDropdownDirective,
  DropdownAnchorDirective,
  DropdownLinkDirective,
  snSideNavToggleDirective,
  RelativeTimePipe,
  ExcerptPipe,
  GetValueByKeyPipe
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    PerfectScrollbarModule,
    SharedMaterialModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    TranslateModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  entryComponents: [AppComfirmComponent, 
    AppLoaderComponent, 
    DialogSearchComponent],
  providers: [
    RoutePartsService,
    AuthGuard,
    AppConfirmService,
    AppLoaderService,
    CommonApiService,
    ScriptService
  ],
  declarations: classesToInclude,
  exports: [classesToInclude]
})

export class SharedModule { }
```

pub.shared.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CategoryNavigationService } from './services/category-navigation.service';
import { PubHeaderComponent} from './components/pub-header/pub-header.component'
import { PubLayoutComponent } from './components/layouts/pub-layout/pub-layout.component';
import { PubFooterComponent } from './components/pub-footer/pub-footer.component';
import { PubLayoutService } from './services/pub-layout.service';
import { CatalogService } from './services/catalog.service';
import { SeoService } from './services/seo.service';
import { SalesService } from './services/sales.service';
import { SharedMaterialModule} from './shared-material.module';
import { SharedModule } from './shared.module';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { PerfectScrollbarModule, PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG, PerfectScrollbarConfigInterface } from 'ngx-perfect-scrollbar';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';

const classesToInclude = [
    PubFooterComponent,
    PubLayoutComponent,
    PubHeaderComponent,
];

const DEFAULT_PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG: PerfectScrollbarConfigInterface = {
    suppressScrollX: true
  };

@NgModule({
    declarations: classesToInclude,
    imports: [SharedMaterialModule, SharedModule, RouterModule, MatSidenavModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule, BrowserModule, PerfectScrollbarModule],
    providers:[
    CategoryNavigationService,
    PubLayoutService,
    CatalogService,
    SeoService,
    SalesService,
    { provide: PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG, useValue: DEFAULT_PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG },
    ],
    exports: classesToInclude
})
export class PubSharedModule {}
```

> Notice I have imported some modules again and I have not imported this
> to my root level module.

I can forward more code if required.

Edit: As soon as I import this pub.shared.module to the root level module. Everything works fine.

Comment: ca you please share error?

Comment: error NG8001: 'mat-sidenav-container' is not a known element and many like this. I know why this is happening, My PubLayout component is router outlet and getting imported by root level module and thus missing dependecies in that module.